# a div animates outside the screen with rapid clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".subscriptions").click(function (){

        if($(".pollSlider").css("margin-right") == "-200px"){
            $('.pollSlider').animate({"margin-right": '+=200'});
            }else{
            $('.pollSlider').animate({"margin-right": '-=200'});
            }
        });

//other exceptions

if($(".pollSlider").css("margin-right") > "200px"){
    $(".pollSlider").css({'margin-righ':'200px'});
    }
if($(".pollSlider").css("margin-right") < "0px"){
    $(".pollSlider").css({'margin-righ':'0px'});
    }
 });
```

this is the css:

```
.pollSlider{
    overflow: auto;
    top:0px;
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    width:200px;
    right:0px;
    margin-right: -200px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

I have a div, when the user click a button the div slides from the left 200px into the screen and when the user clicks the same button again the div animate to the right 200px. This system works very good but the problem is, if the user kept clicking while the div animating left or right, the div will animate out side the screen (to the right) and does not come back again when the user clicks again. So I tried to add the //other exceptions but those if statements did not work. How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried using `.stop()` just before the `.animate()`?

Comment: like that $('.pollSlider').stop(); ??

Comment: yes it should be something like `$('.pollSlider').stop().animate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N6kv9/1/)** where I tried to achieve the effect you're trying to produce. As mentioned in the comments, jQuery [`.stop(…)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) is used to empty the animation queue before starting the next animation.

I also changed the units from relative (`+=200` and `-=200`) to fixed numbers (`0` and `-width`). If you assume the animation will be stopped midstream and you'll need to animate back, you'll need to use either fixed numbers, or do the calculation on the fly before each new animation.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this kind of problem is to add a global variable nad set it to false after user click and set it back to tru when the animation is done:

```
var allowAnimate = true;
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".subscriptions").click(function (){
    if(allowAnimate){
    if($(".pollSlider").css("margin-right") <= "-200px"){
        allowAnimate = false;
        $('.pollSlider').animate({"margin-right": '+=200'}, function(){allowAnimate = true});
        }else if($(".pollSlider").css("margin-right") >= "200px")){
        $('.pollSlider').animate({"margin-right": '-=200'}, function(){allowAnimate = true});
        }
    }
    });

//other exceptions
....
```

So if User click a button the variable `allowAnimate` is checked if its `true`, I set it to `false`, and the animation will began, on the animation callback function I set it back to `true`.

Comment: I just tried your code and I still have the same exact problem.

Comment: Yes because You haven't secure the code :) . You should also check what: `if($(".pollSlider").css("margin-right") >= "200px")`